# Finding Index in string C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, indexing

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int contain(vector<string> &s_vector, string check)
    {
    cout<<"Input a string to check: ";
    cin>>check;
    if(s_vector=check) 
     return find(&s_vector);
    else
    return -1;
    }

int main(){
    vector<string>s_vector;

    cout<<"Input the size of string vector: ";
    int size;
    cin>>size;

    cout<<"Input "<<size<<"strings: \n"; 
    cin>>s_vector[size];

    cout<<"Strings in the string vector: ";
    for(int i=0; i<s_vector.size(); i++)
    cout<<s_vector[i]<<" ";

    contain(s_vector, string check);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a code where you can find the index of a string. For example the output would be like:

```
Input the size of string vector: 3
Input 3 strings:
asd
lkj
qere
Input a string to check: lkj
1
```

But there seems to be some errors in the int contain~section, and if I take out the int contain~ section and run the program, it keeps saying "the run has stopped"whenever I try to input the strings. I'm new to C++ so I could really use your help thanks.

Comment: `cin>>s_vector[size];`  You can not do that. s_vector at this point has 0 elements. Also you need a loop to input 0.. size -1.

Comment: `if(s_vector=check)` Is an assignment not a comparison. Look at your c++ book on operator `==` and operator `=`

Comment: You need to compare each element in the vector to the searchstring, not the vector itself. Comparing is done with `==`, currently you're trying to assign a string to a vector.

Comment: what is `if(s_vector=check)` ? Assigning a `string` to `vector<string>` or comparing them?

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code. Using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator. Fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between a vector, and an individual element. Passing a function parameter defined as "string check", which makes no sense whatsoever. There's simply too many problems here. If, as you say you're "new" to C++, looks like you need to spend more time going over some fundamental topics, before handling a relatively complicated task like this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code is beyond salvageable.

Answer (score 1):

What your contain function might look like:

```
int contain(const vector<string>& s_vector)
{
    cout << "Input a string to check: ";
    string check;
    cin >> check;
    for (int i = 0; i < s_vector.size(); i++)
        if (s_vector[i] == check)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

There's no need to pass the local variable `check` to the function. We're comparing the strings inside the vector one by one by using operator [].
main would look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string>s_vector;

    cout<<"Input the size of string vector: ";
    int size;
    cin>>size;

    cout << "Input " << size << "strings: \n"; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        s_vector.push_back(str);
    }

    cout<<"Strings in the string vector: ";
    for(int i=0; i<s_vector.size(); i++)
    cout<<s_vector[i]<<" ";

    int i = contain(s_vector);
    cout << "Index: " << i;

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Just what I was about to post. Also, the local variable check was never declared nor was a value assigned to it in the main function and calling it by using `string check` as parameter will surely not work.